# Fifth columns from UNION are of different data type in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I am a SAS Developer. I am using PROC SQL to perform union statement.
My code:

```
proc sql;
create table test3 as
select a.state 
,a.station 
,a.ca_no
,a.applicant_name
,a.capacity
,a.commission_date
,a.technology
,a.pmu
,a.ppu
,a.ssu_pe
,a.re_switch_no
,a.voltage
,a.vcb_brand_and_model
,a.scada_y_n
,a.gps_coordinate
,a.plant_manager_phone_number
,a.plant_manager_name
,a.plant_manager_email
,a.highest_md_recorded_a
,a.highest_md_recorded_kw
,a.total_energy_sold
%do c=1 %to 12;
,a.kwh_&&ALLDATES&c..
%end;
%do c=1 %to 12;
,a.gen_factor_&&ALLDATES&c..
%end;
,a.period
from test a
union all
select b.pss_no as ca_no
,b.applicant_name /*capacity_mw voltage technology*/
,b.program
,b.scod_date 
,b.kick_off_date
from newresheet2 b;
quit;
```

As you can see, only ca_no in both table after the rename statement in table B block.

I am getting the error:

> MPRINT(TRASPOSETRX):   proc sql; MPRINT(TRASPOSETRX):   create table
>   test3 as select a.state ,a.station ,a.ca_no ,a.applicant_name
>   ,a.capacity ,a.commission_date ,a.technology ,a.pmu ,a.ppu ,a.ssu_pe
>   ,a.re_switch_no ,a.voltage ,a.vcb_brand_and_model ,a.scada_y_n
>   ,a.gps_coordinate  ,a.plant_manager_phone_number ,a.plant_manager_name
>   ,a.plant_manager_email ,a.highest_md_recorded_a
>   ,a.highest_md_recorded_kw ,a.total_energy_sold ,a.kwh_SEPT17
>   ,a.kwh_OCT17 ,a.kwh_NOV17 ,a.kwh_DEC17 ,a.kwh_JAN18 ,a.kwh_FEB18
>   ,a.kwh_MAR18 ,a.kwh_APR18  ,a.kwh_MAY18 ,a.kwh_JUN18 ,a.kwh_JULY18
>   ,a.kwh_AUG18 ,a.gen_factor_SEPT17 ,a.gen_factor_OCT17
>   ,a.gen_factor_NOV17 ,a.gen_factor_DEC17 ,a.gen_factor_JAN18
>   ,a.gen_factor_FEB18 ,a.gen_factor_MAR18 ,a.gen_factor_APR18
>   ,a.gen_factor_MAY18 ,a.gen_factor_JUN18  ,a.gen_factor_JULY18
>   ,a.gen_factor_AUG18 ,a.period from test a union all select b.pss_no as
>   ca_no ,b.applicant_name ,b.program ,b.scod_date ,b.kick_off_date from
>   newresheet2 b; WARNING: A table has been extended with null columns to
>   perform the UNION ALL set operation. ERROR: Column 5 from the first
>   contributor of UNION ALL is not the same type as its counterpart from
>   the second.

I checked on the datatype for ca_no in both table and both are character. When i count the fifth columns from table A, which is the capacity, i do not have a column called Capacity in table B. In fact i commented out Capacity_MW from table B which do not share the same name. Is this the cause?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE test3 AS

SELECT
   a.STATE
 , a.station
 , a.ca_no
 , a.applicant_name
 , a.capacity
      --------- more than 5 -----------
 , a.commission_date
 , a.technology
 , a.pmu
 , a.ppu
 , a.ssu_pe
 , a.re_switch_no
 , a.voltage
 , a.vcb_brand_and_model
 , a.scada_y_n
 , a.gps_coordinate
 , a.plant_manager_phone_number
 , a.plant_manager_name
 , a.plant_manager_email
 , a.highest_md_recorded_a
 , a.highest_md_recorded_kw
 , a.total_energy_sold
 , a.kwh_SEPT17
 , a.kwh_OCT17
 , a.kwh_NOV17
 , a.kwh_DEC17
 , a.kwh_JAN18
 , a.kwh_FEB18
 , a.kwh_MAR18
 , a.kwh_APR18
 , a.kwh_MAY18
 , a.kwh_JUN18
 , a.kwh_JULY18
 , a.kwh_AUG18
 , a.gen_factor_SEPT17
 , a.gen_factor_OCT17
 , a.gen_factor_NOV17
 , a.gen_factor_DEC17
 , a.gen_factor_JAN18
 , a.gen_factor_FEB18
 , a.gen_factor_MAR18
 , a.gen_factor_APR18
 , a.gen_factor_MAY18
 , a.gen_factor_JUN18
 , a.gen_factor_JULY18
 , a.gen_factor_AUG18
 , a.period
FROM test a
```

That part has many more than 5 columns: the following part does have 5 columns:

```
UNION ALL

SELECT
   b.pss_no AS ca_no
 , b.applicant_name
 , b.program
 , b.scod_date
 , b.kick_off_date
FROM newresheet2 b;
```

A union requires the same number of columns in each subquery, and that each of those columns must be of "compatible" data types (e.g. integer will go into decimal column, but varchar will not go into a date column).

Are EACH these column pairs compatible?

```
SELECT
   a.STATE
 , a.station
 , a.ca_no
 , a.applicant_name
 , a.capacity
FROM test a

UNION ALL

SELECT
   b.pss_no         AS ca_no
 , b.applicant_name
 , b.program
 , b.scod_date
 , b.kick_off_date
FROM newresheet2 b;
```

"Alignment" of columns is NOT achieved by column name/alias, but by position in the select clause, below the a.ca_no is aligned to b.pss_no, and a.applicant_name is aligned to b.applicant_name

```
SELECT
   a.ca_no
 , a.applicant_name
FROM test a

UNION ALL

SELECT
   b.pss_no         AS ca_no
 , b.applicant_name
FROM newresheet2 b;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the query before `UNION ALL` is having more number of columns projected than the query after the `UNION ALL` operator.

You need to make sure that both the queries select same number of coulmns.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way to fix this problem is to append using set statement and it will appends using column name rather column position

```
   /*create table example of your first dataset. table with more columns*/
   data class1;
  set sashelp.class;
  run;

 /*create table example for your second dataset with fewer column and a different name*/

     data class(keep = name age gender);
    set sashelp.class;
    gender =sex;
     run;



   /* append it using set statement using rename. same name column append together, 
    missing values for other columns where there is no match*/

    data want;
   set class1 class(rename = (gender=sex));
   run;
```

you can also use proc append, it also appends using column name rather column position.